# How to open autocad and draw shapes?

Tags: autocad

I have a question.I have an application that users can draw various shapes on it.

I'd like to have a button so when it is clicked autocad opens and my shapes appear in autocad.how can I do this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your shapes in `dwg` or `dxf` format. If you're already using `ObjectARX` it should be easy, if not, you might want to read about it. You can then open the file normally or run Autocad with the file name as a parameter to open it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write an AutoCAD plugin by using AutoCAD.Net SDK instead of writing application out of AutoCAD.

AutoCAD has no feature like office application for controlling it like Microsoft.Office.Interop for accessing from out of it.